# Undefined variable: pseudo

Tags: php

I have an input when I write inside , I want to retrieve the entry in the same page just after the form.

I use a variable `$_GET['pseudo']` but after I save the value on another variable which is $pseudo I have an error message: 
**Notice: Undefined variable: pseudo in C:\wamp\www\revision\index.php on line 27**

It'is here the problem

```
<?php 
    echo "Pseudo : " .$pseudo; 
?>
```

Here is my code for information

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['pseudo']) AND !empty($_GET['pseudo']))
{
    $pseudo = $_GET['pseudo'];
}

?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="fr">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Page d'accueil</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="index.php" method="GET">
            <label for="pseudo">Pseudo : </label>
            <input type="text" id="pseudo" name="pseudo" >
            <input type="submit" value="valider" >
    </form>

    <?php 
        echo "Pseudo : " .$pseudo; 
    ?>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Regards

Comment: if(isset($pseudo)){
 
        echo "Pseudo : " .$pseudo; 
  
 }

Comment: Will `$pseudo` be defined if the get variable is empty or not set?

Comment: Maybe GET pseudo is empty. Then $pseudo will be undefined. Add an else to the if and echo something in the else

Comment: You don't need `empty()` and `isset()`

Comment: @hans-afrik: thank a lot my problem is resolve

Comment: Great. Fantastic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code below is retrieving $pseudo at the time index.php is loaded, which is still not defined as of the moment.

```
<?php 
echo "Pseudo : " .$pseudo; 
?>
```

In order to show Pseudo only when it is defined, you also need to place  `isset` on this part as shown below.

```
<?php 
if(isset($pseudo))
{
    echo "Pseudo : " .$pseudo;
} 
?>
```